# Is there a way to manually remove a Microsoft Outlook add-on?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I intalled a Outlook add-on that connected by calendar to a service. I no longer use the service so I close Outlook and then removed the addon from Windows 10 add/remove programs service.

The addon no longer shows in the Remove Programs list, but it is still appearing in Outlook 2013's Manage Add-ins area.

Is there a way I can manually remove an orphaned Outlook add-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

On the ribbon, `FILE` -> `Options` -> `Add-Ins` -> Manage (at the bottom) `COM Add-ins` -> `Go...` -> Select the add-in you want to remove -> `Remove` button.

Comment: Thanks, it looked like I was getting close. But in Outlook 2013, I find no Manage or Delete button.  This is what I'm looking at. https://screencast.com/t/NllxDwuq

Comment: I performed the entire process in Office 2013 as I wrote the steps. Look... well, on my laptop's screen, it's about two inches lower than that arrow. Right above the bottom of the window. I did specify "Manage **(at the bottom)**". Manage itself isn't a button (or I'd have `marked` it like one) but it helps you find the drop-down and button that you need.

Comment: Yes!  There it is. Thank you for the follow up.  Manage>Com Add-Ins>Go, then highlight and remove. Worked perfectly and solved my problem.

Comment: @DarrenLeno Glad to hear that worked. Please mark the answer as accepted to help others find it.